# How to fix NextJS: "next_intl__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useFormatter) is not a function"?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-intl

I am walking through NextJS documentation and stumble upon the [next-intl](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/dates-times) library. However, I can't make it work.

When following the official docs of `next-intl`, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: (0 ,
> next_intl__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useFormatter) is not a function

Code:

```
import { useFormatter } from 'next-intl';

export default async function BlogComponent({ blog,}: { blog: Blog; }) {
  const format = useFormatter();

  const dt = format.dateTime(blog.pubDate, {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
  });

  return <div>...</div>

}
```

How to fix that?

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.10",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "13.4.10",
    "next-intl": "^2.19.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.26",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as just using the formatter.

You have to follow the instructions for setting up next-intl with server components.

Specifically you will to setup the middleware and next.config.js to use it next-intl.

https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components